# Doing some round robin scheduling math

Tags: scheduling, round-robin

This is the question I faced and couldn't solve it:

Five processes with computation times: `x`, `5`, `8`, `6`, `10` request entering at `t=0`.
Average waiting time is `20ms`. Find `X` if we use `FCFS`, `SJF`, Round Robin (quantum=1ms)
I solved it with `FCFS` and `SJf -> x` is around 14
But how to solve with Round Robin?
Round Robin uses time slices and if we assume `x > 10` (which seems to be) then the waiting time would be independent from the value of x.

Answer (score 0):

if we have compute times as u say, the formula for finding out the average is

((5A + 4B + 3C + 2D + F)/5) = 20.

Reducing we get (5X + 20 + 24 + 12 + 10) = 100

Finally just a simple equation x = 34/5 ~ 7

Comment: Where did you got that formula from? Also if x is going to be 7 then the waiting times would be 23, 17, 25, 22, 26 respectively (calculated by drawing the gannt chart) and the average would then become 22.